# Google Maps: toggle KML when marker is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Maps page which is created by getting information from database and place markers using this information. There are field kml which contains a link to a kml file.

I would like to show this kml as a polygon when the corresponding marker is clicked.

So every marker has it's own kml.

I already can show the polygon when the marker is clicked, but I need them to toggle so that when one marker is clicked, it shows it's kml, but when you click another marker it has to remove the previous polygon, and show the new one.

Basically the same think that happens with info window for the marker.

**UPDATED:**

I use this code:

```
<?php
  // require("connect db");

  $queryLocations = "
    SELECT l.name, l.gpslat, l.gpslong, l.kml, l.id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.model ORDER BY c.model ASC SEPARATOR '</br>') AS cars, COUNT(c.model) AS count
    FROM locations AS l
    JOIN cars AS c
    ON l.invers_id = c.location_id
    WHERE l.status = 'Activa'
    AND l.city = 91
    AND l.name like '%/ Zona%'
    GROUP BY l.name
  ";
  $locations = $db->query($queryLocations);
  $rowLocations = $locations->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
      .cars { margin-top: 5px; }
      .details { margin-top: 5px; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAIbL_AXIspL0t6trcEBQPEXzhK9NTGS7k">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.430013, -3.695854),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

        var location = <?php echo json_encode($rowLocations);?>;

        function displayLocation(location) {
          var kmlArray = [];
          var index = kmlArray.length;
          var addMarker = function(position, title, kml) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map, 
              position: position,
              title: title,
              index: index,
            });

            var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
              url: kml,
              preserveViewport: true,
              suppressInfoWindows: true
            });

            kmlArray.push(ctaLayer);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              var clickedindex = marker.get('index');
              console.log('clicked marker ',clickedindex);

              kmlArray.forEach(function(kml) {
                kml.setMap(null);
              });

              kmlArray[clickedindex].setMap(map);

              infowindow.setContent(location.name + marker.index + location.id);
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
          };

          addMarker({lat:parseFloat(location.gpslat), lng:parseFloat(location.gpslong)},location.name,'http://equipo.bluemove.es/mapas/' + location.kml);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
            displayLocation(location[i]);
          }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

So when I click the marker, polygon is show, but it stay there when I click another marker.

P.S. when I do `echo $json_encode($rowLocations);` I'm getting something like this:

```
[ { name: 'Barrio Centro / Zona 92 Arg?elles Sur (Entre Buen Suceso, Plaza de Espa?a y Cuesta de San Vicente (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.42631149292',
    gpslong: '-3.7155029773712',
    kml: '92_Arguelles_Sur.kml',
    id: '97',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Plata</br>KIA Rio 5p Rojo',
    count: '2' },
  { name: 'Barrio Chamart?n / Zona 55 Nueva Espa?a (Entre Alberto Alcocer y Mateo Inurria (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.463249206543',
    gpslong: '-3.68239402771',
    kml: '55_Nueva_Espana.kml',
    id: '84',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco</br>KIA Rio 5p Rojo',
    count: '3' },
  { name: 'Barrio Chamber? / Zona 76 Vallehermoso_Este (Entre Guzm?n el Bueno y Bravo Murillo (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.443111419678',
    gpslong: '-3.707820892334',
    kml: '76_Vallehermoso_Este.kml',
    id: '89',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco',
    count: '1' },
  { name: 'Barrio Chamberi / Zona 71 Gaztambide (Entre Blasco de Garay e Isaac Peral y Pricesa (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.435173034668',
    gpslong: '-3.7147951126099',
    kml: '72_GAZTAMBIDE.kml',
    id: '85',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco',
    count: '1' },
  { name: 'Barrio Chamberi / Zona 72 Arapiles (Entre Blasco de Garay, Bravo Murillo y San Bernardo (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.434795379639',
    gpslong: '-3.7082290649414',
    kml: '72_Arapiles.kml',
    id: '92',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco</br>KIA Rio 5p Rojo',
    count: '3' },
  { name: 'Barrio Chamberi / Zona 74 Almagro (Entre Santa Engracia y Paseo de la Castellana (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.431015014648',
    gpslong: '-3.6925220489502',
    kml: '74_Almagro.kml',
    id: '70',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco</br>KIA Rio 5p Marron</br>KIA Rio 5p Rojo',
    count: '6' },
  { name: 'Barrio Chamberi / Zona 75 Rios Rosas (Entre Raimundo Fernandez Villaverde y Jos? Abascal (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.442276000977',
    gpslong: '-3.6977150440216',
    kml: '75_RIOS_ROSAS.kml',
    id: '86',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco</br>KIA Rio 5p Plata</br>KIA Rio 5p Rojo',
    count: '3' },
  { name: 'Barrio Hispanoamerica / Zona 54 Este (Entre Principe de Vergara y Avenida de la Paz (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.455364227295',
    gpslong: '-3.6698839664459',
    kml: '54_Hispanoamerica_Este.kml',
    id: '83',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco 1</br>KIA Rio 5p Blanco 2</br>KIA Rio 5p Rojo',
    count: '3' },
  { name: 'Barrio Hispanoamerica / Zona 54 Oeste (Entre Alberto Alcocer y Concha Espina (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.455436706543',
    gpslong: '-3.6824150085449',
    kml: '54_Hispanoamerica_Oeste.kml',
    id: '75',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco',
    count: '1' },
  { name: 'Barrio Salamanca / Zona 41 Recoletos (Entre Alcal?, O?Donnell y Don Ram?n de la Cruz (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.425373077393',
    gpslong: '-3.6854410171509',
    kml: '41_Recoletos.kml',
    id: '91',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Rojo',
    count: '1' },
  { name: 'Barrio Salamanca / Zona 46 Castellana (Entre Maria Molina y Don Ramon de la Cruz (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.432849884033',
    gpslong: '-3.6840240955353',
    kml: '46_Castellana.kml',
    id: '73',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco',
    count: '2' },
  { name: 'Barrio Tetuan / Zona 62 Cuatro Caminos (Entre Raimundo Fernandez Villaverde y General Yag?e (Situado en la calle)',
    gpslat: '40.45157623291',
    gpslong: '-3.6967279911041',
    kml: '62_Cuatro_Caminos.kml',
    id: '79',
    cars: 'KIA Rio 5p Blanco',
    count: '2' } ]
```

You can see how it works on `http://188.226.231.156/~burdiyan/mapa/concatenated.php`

Please check this page, that how I want it to work: https://www.zebramobil.de/ click "Start demonstration"

Thank you!

Comment: What issues are you having doing that?  Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue? A [jsfiddle](http://jsffiddle.net) that exhibits the problem would be helpful as well.

Comment: and this is why I should learn not to get carried away with my answers :(

Comment: I'm sorry for not giving a good example of what I have, I just can't make it work using bl.ocks.org and don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of every kml layer you add, so you can later toggle it. In this case, I'd reccomend declaring an array, so you can later iterate through it turning every kml off before turning the active one on.

For convenience, I made a function to encapsulate this behavior

```
// I declare an array called kmlArray to store a reference to my kml layers
var kmlArray=[];

// I declare a function that expects a position, a title and a kml url
var addMarker=function(position, title, kml) {

    // i'll give each marker an index property equal to the elements in kmlArrays
    var index=kmlArray.length;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: position,
                title: title,
                index:index
              });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                  url: kml, 
                  preserveViewport: true,
                  suppressInfoWindows: true
                });

    // I add the kml layer I just created to my kmlArray.
    kmlArray.push(ctaLayer);


    // I add the behavior to the click event on the marker I'm adding
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
        // I retrieve the index property I gave the marker.  
        var clickedindex=marker.get('index');
        console.log('clicked marker ',clickedindex);

        // I loop through all my kml layers turning them off
        kmlArray.forEach(function(kml) {
            kml.setMap(null);
        });

        // I turn on the kml element whose index corresponds to the marker I just clicked
        kmlArray[clickedindex].setMap(map);
    });
};
```

I made an example for you with 4 texas counties.
See it working: http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/b0bc74a37e8438c63d43

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. It looks like a good solution, but the problem I have is that I don't have specific amount of markers. The are dynamic and depend of the database. So every time I click the marker it goes to the database to get it's kml url. I will update the original post with an example of what I do.

Comment: I updated the original post with the new code. I think the problem is that since markers are dynamic, they always will have 0 index. I suppose that there is some way to increment the index with every marker I click, and store it in the array, but I don't know how, I'm pretty new to this. Thank you!

Comment: @amendiel I have minimized the code for better reading. It is complete working example right now. Do you think it would be possible to reach what I wanted with that? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I cannot look at it right now, but I'll sure do before noon

Comment: Wait, it's simpler than I thought. You just need to declare the kmlarray **outside** the function. The way you have it now, you're resetting the whole collection everytime you add a marker.